# Six sided die probability

Tags: probability

> A six-sided die is rolled, and the number $N$ on the uppermost face is
> recorded. Given $N$, the die is rolled again for $N$ times independently, and,
> each time, the number on the uppermost face is recorded. Let $X$ be the
> smallest number recorded in these $N$ rolls.
>
> a)  What is $Pr(X = 2)$?
>
> b)  Let $Y = \min\{X, N\}$. What is $Pr(Y = 2)$?

my attempt:[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DdZ44.jpg)

can someone check if my q(a) is correct and help me a bit with q(b)?

Comment: Nothing here is Bin. To find X=2 use the distribution of the minimum of N rolls for a given N, then sum all using the law of complete probability.

Answer (score 0):

Hint:

Throwing the die $N$ times one can obtain altogether $6^N$ combinations of faces. To obtain $X=x$ the combination should contain at least one $x$ and no $x<X$. There are $(7-x)^N$ combinations which contain no face counts less than $x$ and $(6-x)^N$ combinations which contain no face counts less than $x+1$. Therefore
$$
Pr(X=x)=\frac16\sum_{N=1}^6\frac{(7-x)^N-(6-x)^N}{6^N}.
$$

For the part b consider separately the cases $\{N>2,X=2\},\{N=2,X\ge 2\}$.

Answer (score 0):

Start for problem b):

After rolling the first die roll $6$ times and let $X_1,\dots, X_6$ denote the outcomes.

Then let $X:=\min(\{X_1,\dots,X_N\})$.

Note that $X_1,X_2,\dots,X_6,N$ are independent.

$\begin{aligned}P\left(Y=2\right) & =\sum_{k=1}^{6}P\left(\min\left\{ X,N\right\} =2\mid N=k\right)P\left(N=k\right)\\
 & =\frac{1}{6}\sum_{k=2}^{6}P\left(\min\left\{ X,k\right\} =2\mid N=k\right)\\
 & =\frac{1}{6}P\left(\min\left\{ X,2\right\} =2\mid N=2\right)+\frac{1}{6}\sum_{k=3}^{6}P\left(\min\left\{ X,k\right\} =2\mid N=k\right)\\
 & =\frac{1}{6}P\left(X\geq2\mid N=2\right)+\frac{1}{6}\sum_{k=3}^{6}P\left(X=2\mid N=k\right)\\
 & =\frac{1}{6}P\left(X_{1}\geq2,X_{2}\geq2\mid N=2\right)+\frac{1}{6}\sum_{k=3}^{6}P\left(\min\left(X_{1},\dots,X_{k}\right)=2\mid N=k\right)\\
 & =\frac{1}{6}P\left(X_{1}\geq2,X_{2}\geq2\right)+\frac{1}{6}\sum_{k=3}^{6}P\left(\min\left(X_{1},\dots,X_{k}\right)=2\right)
\end{aligned}
$

The last equality rests on  independence.

Can you take it from here?